# Evento para nav-tab do Bootstrap rodar no lado do servidor c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Estou usando o seguinte código para usar tabs em minha aplicação Asp.Net, existe alguma forma de adicionar um evento para que quando trocar de aba executar algum evento no lado do servidor igual o evento da TabContainer do ajaxcontroltoolkit ? (http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/Tabs/Tabs.aspx)

Não estou usando a TabContainer pelo motivo de não conseguir aplicar o Bootstrap nela.

Encontrei o código abaixo mas ele faz no lado do cliente.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705905/bootstrap-3-jquery-event-for-active-tab-change

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var target = $(e.target).attr("href") // activated tab
  alert(target);
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="home">
    home tab!
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
    profile tab!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: O evento vai ser síncrono ou assíncrono? Você pode utilizar ajax?

Comment: ajaxcontroltoolkit.com é seu site ? Se sim, onde voce hospedou ?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda ajaxcontroltoolkit.com não é meu, apenas ultilizei o componente. Agora ele ele mantido pela DevExpress: https://www.devexpress.com/products/ajax-control-toolkit/ Documentação: https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de você usar link normal você pode usar LinkButton do asp.net e pegar o evento do click no lado do servidor:

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><asp:LinkButton data-toggle="tab" OnClick="Method_Click">Home</a></li>
<li class=""><asp:LinkButton data-toggle="tab" OnClick="Method_Click"></li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
 <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="home">
     home tab!
  </div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
    profile tab!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seu código não funciona mas você me deu uma luz usando LinkButton, depois vou colocar minha resposta para que possa ver. De qualquer forma obrigado.

Comment: Não funcionou, mesmo usando runat="server"?